# How to link youtube video without captions?

Tags: xhtml, youtube, embed, closed-captions

Is it possible to link **youtube** videos in HTML code without showing it's captions (subtitles)?

Let's say I have following video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTvHIDKLFqc . It has default english subtitles. However, when linking this video, I want to load it without them. Is there a possibility to do so with some kind of parameter in video?

I found [this link](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140174) with description how to do it, but it doesn't seem to work. If I try to use following format of link, it shows captions anyway: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTvHIDKLFqc&cc_load_policy=0. Is it not working or did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: The link does only explain how to force captions, not how to disable it..

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm asking this question. I cannot find anything about how to turn it off. I assumed setting cc_load_policy to 0 would do it, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: why would you want to disable subtitles/cc?

Comment: @netrox: because client wanted it back then, don't ask me why

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/youtube/-RAqv6DCciM/NnauvUKlx_IJ

Comment: YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters : https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the documentation to be a little misleading in that setting &cc_load_policy=1 does not show the closed captions by default, but enables toggling with the cc button in the video control bar when entered as shown here -

http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140174

Answer (score 4):

It seems `cc_load_policy` is a parameter that only accepts `1` as value, so even if you try to use `0` or `off` values to turn off captions, it won't make a difference (at least until today: <strike>2015-05-18</strike> 2017-09-11):
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#cc_load_policy

## 2017-09-11 Solution: "Enable privacy-enhanced mode"

When you share a video in Youtube through the embedding option, you can click the "Enable privacy-enhanced mode" checkbox. This will change the URL to a **different Youtube domain**: `https://www.youtube-nocookie.com`

Just by doing this, even if the user has captions *On* by default, the *nocookie* option will not read the cookie associated to the user preferences (it's as if the user does not require captions by default).

I have created this [**codepen** example](https://codepen.io/Armfoot/pen/RLbpjd) in order to explain this:

1. Try playing the "No parameters" video and then the `cc_load_policy=1` video (it may not display captions due to user preferences, even if in the latter the CC button is activated - red underline);
2. Then play the "nocookie domain" video and there should be no captions.
3. Try activating captions in the "no parameters" video and refresh the page.
4. All videos except the "nocookie domain" video will display captions.

Disclaimer: I have only seen this working in Chrome (Firefox and Edge always display captions in the nocookie domain, even in private navigations). If you activate/deactivate captions manually in the "nocookie domain" video, then it will display/hide captions in this domain when you refresh the page respectively.

### Old stuff (partial solution for owners of the video)

`cc_lang_pref` does not accept `off` or `Off` as a value either...

I managed to turn off captions/subtitles for the default language of the video this way **only for Safari and IE** (I have captions in the default language and English - in my case, Chrome and Firefox seemed to have ignored the change, but I suggest to give it a shot anyway):

1. In youtube if you go to your video's **Info and Settings** page and click **Advanced Settings** tab, set the **Video Language** to `Not applicable`.
2. Save and go to **Subtitles and CC** page, where a pop-up appears explaining that *«You must select a video language before adding subtitles or CC.»* (this seems not to be true, because they even appear anyway).
3. Choose **your video's default language** in the pop-up: <strike>this is what makes it understand that you don't need captions of your default language when the video is in the same default language</strike> the weird thing is, this is the step that will make them not to show up, and it's not because the same language is used in the captions.
4. In the URL's video that you do not want to have captions *do not use* `cc_load_policy` parameter, but you can use `cc_lang_pref` to the default language like this:
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTvHIDKLFqc&cc_lang_pref=en.

Again, this seems to work only in some browsers (Firefox and Chrome not included), but hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

The site says how to turn on caption. It does not talk about turning off captions. I thinkit depends on the user's previous choice.

> When you embed a video on another
>   site, you can make it so that captions
>   are always shown on the embedded
>   video. To enable captions on a video
>   you'd like to embed, just add
>   &cc_load_policy=1 to the video's embed
>   code.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, add `iv_load_policy=3` parameter to your embed code.

Comment: This hides user-added comments

Answer (score 0):

Peace to whom will follow the guidance,

(Thanks for your tries but I found something nice not far away from there...)

Ask for a language preference that is not from the translated captions (for my exemple "He" stands Hebrew, that was not among the offered translations of the video.)

Add ?hl=He to the url, like this :

without it :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRztmbnyV70

and with it :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRztmbnyV70?hl=He

Makes it... ? 
It worked for me on Firefox, Edge and Opera. 
-- Enjoy !

Note : the particle desapears after the loading of the page ...But the job is done !

Comment: May be I illusioned myself... still working in Opera, God willing.