# youtube embed - force subtitles in specific language with default

Tags: youtube-api

i'm embedding youtube videos with subtitles in specific language (Hebrew, in my case). 
im using:

```
hl=He&cc_load_policy=1
```

to show the hebrew subtitles and that works fine.

However, if there are no subs in my language, i would like to see the English one (if there are any) as a default. is there a way to force that?

Comment: The subtitles can be automatically translated, how can I load the video with the automatic translation of the subtitles in english to another language activated, in my case portuguese !?

Answer (score 31):

You can force the captions and language using `cc_load_policy` & `cc_lang_pref` options via

**URL:**

http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=en

**API:**

```
var ytPlayer = new YT.Player(
    ...
    playerVars: {
        cc_load_policy: 1,
        cc_lang_pref: 'en'
    },
    ....
});
```

Credits: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27669/is-there-any-way-to-force-subtitles-in-a-youtube-video

Comment: Thanks - the cc_lang_pref is new to me. ill check it.

Comment: Well detailed and the most accurate now (2015-05-18), this answer should be upvoted. And if you want to force the **captions not to show up**, [I found a way to deal with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287774/how-to-link-youtube-video-without-captions/30302467#30302467) but it's very limited.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work any more.
Even if it would work, I am looking for a way to start playing with "auto-generated and translated" subtitles. Using your method I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Props for the example URL which is also an overview of the API params

Answer (score 5):

I have not found this anywhere in their api docs, but with your youtube player object you should be able to do the following to change it to english captions:

```
player.setOption("captions", "track", {"languageCode": "en"});  //Works for html5 ignored by AS3
player.setOption("cc", "track", {"languageCode": "en"});  //Works for AS3 ignored by html5
```

You can also do:

```
var module;
if (testplayer.getOptions().indexOf("cc") !== -1) {
    module = "cc";
} else if (testplayer.getOptions().indexOf("captions") != -1) {{
    module = "captions";
}
var tracklist = testplayer.getOption(module, "tracklist");

// then iterate through the tracklist to see if "he" or "en" is there.
```

You have cc_load_policy=1 but you can also turn it on via js by:

```
player.loadModule("captions");  //Works for html5 ignored by AS3
player.loadModule("cc");  //Works for AS3 ignored by html5
```

to turn it off:

```
player.unloadModule("captions");  //Works for html5 ignored by AS3
player.unloadModule("cc");  //Works for AS3 ignored by html5
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it would be better to just leave out the hl= entirely. (It's not actually one of our [officially supported Player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).) The subtitles will default to the language preference of the viewer of the video, and my assumption is that it will fall back on English if there are no subtitles in the viewer's preferred language.

Comment: thanks,but - when i remove the "hl" tag, i get the English subtitles even if my preferred language is Hebrew and there are Hebrew subtitles available.

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me, then. Could you use https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report) to open a bug there so that we can track it? And where is your language preference set—I think there's a different location based on whether you have a Google+ account linked to your YouTube account or not.

Comment: Opened - https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3046 i referred to the language setting in the bug description

Comment: In my case, I had 2 languages in my language settings. One preferred language and one secondary language. Every time a youtube video was embedded on a site, it would show up in my secondary language. And everytime a logged in to a Google service, the UI would be in my secondary language. I had to remove my secondary language from the language settings, that stopped this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found is changing the URI from

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s3aJfRr9gE
```

to this pattern

```
"https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/" + video_id + "?hl=" lang_code
```

On bash/Linux you can just copy the URI with that structure and then run this command (Spanish code hardcoded) to transform clipboard content (you can make an alias):

```
xclip -selection c -o | echo "$(cat -)?&amp;hl=es-419" | sed "s|youtube.com/watch?v=|youtube-nocookie.com/embed/|1" | xclip -selection c
```

You can list the available subtitles [ISO 639-1 language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) with [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html):

```
youtube-dl --list-subs "{video_id or url}"
```

The only drawback is that the video will cover the complete screen... which might be good thing to stop procrastinating with related videos :)