# Change language for YouTube embed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the language of the Youtube embed player. For example, to change things like "Full Screen", "Change Quality" etc into German?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

How are you embedding it? If it's simply with the embed url, you can do something like adding the parameters "hl=de" and "persist_hl=1" to the url. Like so:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?hl=de&persist_hl=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

I've only found out about "persist_hl" by adding "hl=de" to a basic youtube page and checking what the url to display youtube in german was. I haven't found any info about it and what it does.

**Edit:**

I doubt my answer is valid. The "persist_hl" parameter will change the user's cookies for youtube's site and force the new language.

**Edit 2:**

Looks like you shouldn't force the language anyways as it should depend on the user's preference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696747/1372543

The answer's from Jeff Posnick, who works for Google. I feel it applies to your question.