# Why is my embeded youtube video only shows up on english version of the website?

Tags: php, html, youtube

I have embeded with an Iframe in my .php page template just like this:

```
    <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YpsgcPowsQ4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

On my localhost it works on both sides (English and french) but once I upload it live, it only shows on the english version of the websites home page, not on the french side home page.

I was wondering if WPML could have something to do with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cache plugin (w3tc) which was not available on the admin but still has been installed. I deleted all folders and files inside plugin's folder + removed all its lines in .htaccess for 24 hours and now restored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hl=(your language)` to set the language manually.

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YpsgcPowsQ4?hl=id&rel=0"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

on this code, i changed it into Indonesian (`id`). Yes you may change it into French (`fr`).

**Take Note**:
You actually shouldn't use the `hl` it self, as let the user use their preference satisfy them self.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696747/1372543

See refrence here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218432

Comment: The thing is, I added the video to the page template , it's actually showing on the english version of my site: http://podiatrebonneau.com/en/ but not on the french side: http://podiatrebonneau.com/.  Probably some rookie mistake but definitely struggling with this one...

Comment: @BrunoLalonde are you using a framework? may i know what is it?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply I actually found out and eill post in answer. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure, my pleasure.