# How To Disable Youtube Captions in a Youtube Embed Link

Tags: javascript, youtube, video.js, closed-captions

When creating an embed link on youtube the Captions are `on` by default. Is there a way to disable to the captions or turning them off when embedding a youtube link?

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en&rd=1) indicates:

```
Make captions automatically appear for an embedded video by adding "&cc_load_policy=1" to the video's embed code.
```

And I need to it the other way around. 
I tried to use `&cc_load_policiy=0` but that didn't work. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287774/how-to-link-youtube-video-without-captions) question but none of the answers seem to work.

I am using also VideoJS. So maybe there is a way to do it through it...

Thanks

Comment: I figured out a [small workaround for no captions in some browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30302467/1326147), just in case you still need it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cc_load_policy (supported players: AS3, AS2) Values: 1. Default is
>   based on user preference. Setting to 1 will cause closed captions to
>   be shown by default, even if the user has turned captions off.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible as it's a user-preference. The cc_load_policy refers to disabling/enabling the toggle button for the player (limited to AS3, AS2 players). And since VideoJS is based off HTML5, I'm imagining the cc_load_policy isn't available for your use either.

Answer (score 14):

Use the same logic as for `iv_load_policy` and set value to `3`:

For example:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WJo98LfIfEA?cc_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Also it works great with JS API for embedded videos.

Comment: Dang, this answer needs to be upvoted! This hidden value for `cc_lang_policy` is nowhere in the YouTube docs and I haven't seen any other thread that even mentions it! Hopefully YouTube doesn't quietly remove it.