# Disable YouTube captions on embedded video

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to embed youtube video with YouTube iframe.

The video has a `yt:cc=on` tag, which means captions will load by default.

(The attribute cc_load_policy=1 force loading captions, even if the user doesn't want it.)

I'm using flash embedding (AS3) which support the `cc_load_policy` attribute. But if i set it to cc_load_policy=0, captions are shown because video has yt:cc=on tag.

Is there any way to hide captions even the video has yt:cc=on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read, the cc_load_policy only supports one value which is 1 and that's also the default unless the user disabled captions. so it looks like you can only force captions on and not off... hope this helps.

> Values: 1. Default is based on user preference. Setting to 1 will cause closed captions to be shown by default, even if the user has turned captions off.

Answer (score 1):

It is undocumented, but setting `cc_load_policy` to `3` seems to work at the moment.

I usually set both `cc_load_policy` & `iv_load_policy` to `1` to force enable captions and both to `3` to force disable them.

That answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300398.